# Multilanguage and form validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, multilingual

I'm creating web site in asp.net web forms. I added validation to fields in form (asp:RequiredFieldValidator) and I'm using multilanguage on page, as following:

I have link buttons like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSetEnglish" runat="server" CommandArgument="en-GB" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click">
  <img src="Images/logos/en.png" alt="English" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And function

```
    protected void RequestLanguageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton senderLink = sender as ImageButton;

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
        cookie.Value = senderLink.CommandArgument;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
        //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(senderLink.CommandArgument);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(senderLink.CommandArgument);
        Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    }
```

I have problem now with validate. When I am on contact form with validating field and this field is empty, when I try change language by click in image inside link, instead of change language of the site, I have commant from validating. What can I do here?

Best regards,
Dagna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CausesValidation to false on the LinkButton